# coupon code applying only one one product instead of whole cart

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

we created shopping cart price rule to give **50 % discount for all cart subtotal.**

but coupon code is applying **only for one product.**

in cart **2 items**,

```
Product 1 [ price - 100] , 
Product 2 [ price - 400] , 
total price = 500
```

when we applied coupon code, it should give **50 %** discount and display as "**250**" , but now its displaying as "50" as discount is applying only for one product.

[image]

[image]

same coupon code working fine in another site [1.9.2.0], i am 100 % sure both have same configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i apply coupon code if order total value is greater than 100 INR?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147442/how-can-i-apply-coupon-code-if-order-total-value-is-greater-than-100-inr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply discount to cart subtotal, you should apply the rule to whole cart. You applied to product price so it is calculated for a product only.

Answer (score 1):

changing `Stop Further Rules Processing : NO` worked for me